# Replacing a whole column in R

Tags: r

I have searched a lot and I didn't find an answer on this.
Let's say we have some data from a .csv file(lets call it xx.csv). Something like this

```
Number  A  B  C ... Z
 1     .. ..  ..
 .
 .
 .
4000  .. ..  .. ... ...
```

You can put whatever you want in A, B, C,...Names, numbers, NAs etc.
So, Whats the easiest way that I replace a whole column (lets say B) with another one external (I mean not one from the csv file)??

Comment: Just assign your external vector to your column : `df$B <- v`

Comment: On the [**info**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) page for the R tag are a lot of resources and tutorials. I'd recommend having a cursory browse through one of these as this is a really fundamental operation in R. [**Assignment**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Simple-manipulations-numbers-and-vectors) is the first topic covered after the preliminaries of *An Introduction to R, a basic introduction for beginners*, and later there is also a whole section on [**`data.frames`**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Data-frames).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With assignment:

```
data$B <- whatever
# or
data[, "B"] <- whatever
# or
data[["B"]] <- whatever
```

Answer (score 5):

First I set up an example `people.csv`.

```
names <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Carol")
ages <- c(18,21,19)
eyecolor <- c("Blue", "Brown", "Brown")
df <- data.frame(names, ages, eyecolor)
write.csv(df, "people.csv")
```

Then I replace the age column by a height column:

```
height <- c(160, 180, 170)
df <- read.csv("people.csv")
df[["ages"]] <- height
colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "ages"] <- "height"
write.csv(df, "people.csv")
```