# How to replace contents of a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a file which contains the data below and I am trying to change the column "condition" comprising "GBM1, GBM10..." to common name just "GBM". 
I need help with R command to convert them to GBM. 
I want to know how to dot it using `dplyr`.

Below is the data..

```
dat <- data.frame(
 sample = c("GSM564972", "GSM564973", "GSM564974"),
 condition= c("GBM1", "GBM10", "GBM11"))
```

Desired output:

```
   sample condition
GSM564972       GBM
GSM564973       GBM
GSM564974       GBM
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing a whole column in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295277/replacing-a-whole-column-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
     mutate(condition = str_extract(condition, "\\D+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use the `sub` function to replace digits with "" (empty string) in combination with `mutate` from `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
# use sub within mutate to change column
mutate(dat, condition = sub("\\d+", "", condition))
```

See [here](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php) for examples of `sub` usage.