# How to change values of a column if I only know the string variable name of the data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Now I have a data frame which is defined as below.

```
df=data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3),x2=c(4,5,6))
```

And I only have the string variable of that data.frame

```
df.str = 'df'
```

How to change a column of `df` (say, assign 0 to `df$x1`) without using variable name `df`? Only `df.str` is allowed therefore you can't write `df$x1=0`.

I tried a lot of ways but none of them worked:

```
df.str$x1=0
df.str[[x1]]=0
df.str[,'x1']=0
```

Comment: `new_df <- get(df.str); new_df$x1 <- 0`

Comment: @RonakShah - it's very close but not sure if a duplicate, given that this is also talking about assignment of a variable within the referenced data.frame.

Comment: @thelatemail I think the main objective of the question is to know `get` or `mget`, once OP gets it, it is pretty easy to replace the column value with 0. I could add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295277/replacing-a-whole-column-in-r) link to the already marked dupe.

Comment: @RonakShah - sure, that might cover it off more cleanly.

Comment: @RonakShah   Actually what I didn't know is the operation '[<-'

Comment: @ZhenduoCao - `\`[<-\`` is essentially just `df["var"] <- 1` put back into functional form - `\`[<-\`(df, "var", 1)`

Comment: @ZhenduoCao just do `get` on your `df.str` and store it a new variable and then try any of the operation which you already tried.

Comment: Creating a new variable defeats the purpose and it is not what the OP asked about

Answer (score 1):

We need `get` to get the value and `assign` to assign the values

```
get(df.str)
assign(df.str, `[<-`(get(df.str), "x1",  value = 0))
```

Now, if we check 'df', the 'x1' column is assigned to 0

```
df
#  x1 x2
#1  0  4
#2  0  5
#3  0  6
```

Comment: Thanks that is helpful